# Always allow access to webcam in Edge kiosk mode

Tags: windows-10, webcam, kiosk

I am using my Surface Pro with Windows 10 Pro as a display and digital signage for my customers.

I have set up the device with assigned access (according to this guide https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/kiosk-single-app#local) using Edge in Kiosk mode with the option `As a digital sign or interactive display` selected.

Everything works fine, except when the browser want to access the webcam (to scan a QR code) it asks for permission EVERY time.

Is there any way to always allow access to the webcam to Edge in Kiosk mode?